# Cruise Control.NET: how to set username and password for git repository task?

Tags: git, passwords, cruisecontrol.net

I'm running a CCNet service on my build server to build a Git repository-based solution. The Git repository is password protected. Is there a way to set the username and password for the source control task?

```
<sourcecontrol type="git">
</sourcecontrol>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

method 1

if you don't care about security, embed password in URL string

```
http://user:password@abcdef.com/abc/def.git
```

method 2

use a git credential helper to store username and password (more secure)

msysgit 1.8.1 or later: set config to enable the built-in git-credential-wincred
    [credential]
        helper = wincred

or install git-credential-winstore for older msysgit

Comment: For security reason, not all servers support method 1. googlecode is an example not to support method 1.

Comment: method 2 didn't help for TFS. Cruise Control user is a user that is allowed to access and using method 1 works. But method 2 would be prefered